# Producing a sequence of ggplot2 plots to make a movie

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to save a sequence of ggplot2 figures as jpg to make a movie (outside of R). I want to show the evolution of my plot where the first image represents a plot of the first line of my csv table, the second image represents the two first lines, and the Nth image represents the Nth first lines, etc.

Here's my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

dat <- read.csv("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73950/dataset.csv", check.names = FALSE)

colnames(dat)[colnames(dat)=="A"] <- "a"
colnames(dat)[colnames(dat)=="B"] <- "b"

res <- do.call(rbind, combn(1:d, 2, function(ii)
  cbind(row=seq(nrow(dat)),setNames(dat[,c(ii, setdiff(1:d, ii))], c("x", "y")),
        var=paste(names(dat)[ii], collapse="/")), simplify=F))

ggplot(res, aes(x=x, y=y, color=row))+ geom_point(shape=20, alpha = .6) +
  scale_color_gradientn("Iter",colours=rev(brewer.pal(9,"Spectral")))
```

The plots' axis need to be bounded so the movie doesn't jump around, as well. How can I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: Check out the `animation` package, Here's a [blog post](http://www.r-bloggers.com/animations-and-gifs-using-ggplot2/) with a ggplot example

Comment: @jeremycg want to turn that into an answer?